# Some Math problems with For Loops and Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

```
var test = [
"test1",
"test2",
"test3",
"test4"
];
var text = "";
for (var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
if (i == test.length) {
    text += test[i] + ". Fin";
    } else {
    text += test[i] + "<br>";
    }
 }
```

In this code I basically attempt to create a list which would result in:
test1
test2
test3
test4. Fin

Everything works except for the . Fin. I believe this is because I am not getting the number properly or something along the lines of that.

**EDIT:** Silly question, messy code from a while back when I was a beginner. The `Array.join()` helped me out here within a line, ending it off by adding a string to the suffix.

Comment: It executes the loop for as long as `i < test.length`.  It will never execute the code in the loop if i is not < test.length.  Change it to `i <= test.length;`

Comment: `i < test.length;` --- `if (i == test.length)`, think again.

Comment: try i <= test.length ... that way you get your beloved . Fin in the end

Comment: @AurA and `undefined`.

Comment: yeah thats the problem. it adds another line marked as undefined with the . Fin after

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is your problem (see comments):

```
for (var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) { // We only execute the code when i < length
  if (i == test.length) {               // But here, you try to add something when it's = !
    text += test[i] + ". Fin";
  } else {
    text += test[i] + "<br>";
  }
}
```

If you want to make it work and *need* to use your `for` loop, here are two different solutions:

```js
var test = ["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4"];

// First solution: Modify your loop
var text = "";
for (var i = 0; i <= test.length; i++) { // Modified < to <=
  if (i == test.length) {
    text += ". Fin"; // Removed "test[i]", because it doesn't exist when i == length
  } else {
    text += test[i] + "<br>";
  }
}
console.log(text);

// Another shorter solution: Add ". Fin" AFTER the loop
var text = "";
for (var i = 0; i < test.length; i++){
  text += test[i] + "<br>";
}
text += ". Fin";
console.log(text);
```

⋅
⋅
⋅

Anyway, if you don't *need* the `for` loop,
there is another easier solution using `.join()`:

```js
var test = [
  "test1",
  "test2",
  "test3",
  "test4"
];

var text = test.join('<br>') + '<br>. Fin';
console.log(text);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I think they're just asking why it doesn't ouput `fin`.  I don't think they're asking how to do it - they just want to understand.

Comment: @Archer Thanks for commenting, I'm going to update with an explanation.

Comment: I may be wrong - the OP isn't exactly clear.  This is obviously correct either way, so have another one from me :)

Comment: Very useful thanks, however, the reason why I had put test[i] there was because if I didn't the <br> on the last test would break it making it be on different lines. So I'm not sure how to bypass that.

Comment: @Masterthias I've edited to add the <br> after the last one in my suggestion. And I've just edited to add another solution using your loop, too.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in JavaScript are zero-based, so you need to check `i == (test.length - 1)` because the `test.length` will be never equal to the last `index`..

Code example:

```js
var test = ["test1","test2","test3","test4"];
var text = "";

for (var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
  var str = (i == (test.length - 1)) ? ". Fin" : "<br>";      
  text += test[i] + str;
}

console.log(text);
```

Comment: @Masterthias it is Good to help!